# Test environment in Node.js / Express application

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, tdd, jasmine

I've just starting working with Node, and I've been following along with various tutorials.

I've created an Express app, and setup Mongoose and Jasmine.

How can I configure my specs so that I can:

- create models, automatically clean them up after each spec
- use a different database for creating test objects (say myapp_test)
- do this in a way that is as DRY as possible, i.e. not creating a before / after block with the teardown for each describe block

?

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to answer you.

> **Create models, automatically clean them up after each spec.**

To do that I'll assume you use Mocha as the testing framework you can simply use the function `beforeEach` like this :

```
describe('POST /api/users', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
        User.remove({}, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Basicly what I'm doing here is cleanning up my database before each `it` but you can make it do anything you want.

> **Use a different database for creating test objects**

Here, you should use the node `process.env` method to setting your env. [Here](http://himanshu.gilani.info/blog/2012/09/26/bootstraping-a-node-dot-js-app-for-dev-slash-prod-environment/) is a article to understand a little how it works. Take a lot to GRUNT projects, it helps a lot with your workflow and the configurations stuff.

> **do this in a way that is as DRY as possible, i.e. not creating a
>   before / after block with the teardown for each describe block**

I'm not sure I got what you want but take a look at the doc for the hooks `before`, `after`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach`. I think you will find what you want here.

Comment: As an addition there is a grunt project called grunt-express-server (https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-express-server) that helps you a lot to setting the env.