# Test environment and test database

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js, should.js

Consider having a test database to run your tests on. One way of doing this is to set the database config through environment variables, and I see many people do so (example: [Test environment in Node.js / Express application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168592/test-environment-in-node-js-express-application/25781967#25781967)).
    However, to me this seems a bit dangerous. All it requires is that sometime in the future, by mistake, the env variable is set to development or production and suddenly we'll be messing with (or even wiping) the wrong database.
    Is there a better way to do this?

(I'm using node/mocha/should.js to run my tests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run production completely separate from development: different servers, databases on different machines, etc. This eliminates a lot of opportunities for messing up. This being said...

Do not write **one** configuration file which will set different configuration values depending on an environment variable. Instead, have the environment variable select an *entirely different configuration file*. Your application could read `config_<env>.js` where `<env>` is the value of the environment variable `MYAPP_ENV`. So if you set `MYAPP_ENV=production`, then the file `config_production.js` would be read to set the configuration. You store the various `config_....js` files **separate** from the code of your application. (A different repository, if you want.) Then, when you deploy, you copy only the production configuration to your deployment server. This way if you goof by setting `MYAPP_ENV=dev` at some point, your application won't find the configuration file and will crash rather than do something harmful.

For maximum safety, *force* yourself to write each configuration file by hand instead of cutting and pasting configuration lines from development to production. The one day you cut and paste the parameters to access a resource can be accessed by both sites and you forget to change it for production, you'll regret having cut and pasted.